# Find closest multiple above and below value R

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the values above and below a variable that fall on a multiple, preferably in a `dplyr::mutate`.

In this simplified example. I want to determine the multiple of 50 both above and below my values of `x`.  I am under the impression `cut` is what I should use, but I haven't gotten it to work.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(265, 617, 88, 99, 143, 378)
)

    x
1 265
2 617
3  88
4  99
5 143
6 378
```

```
desired_result <- data.frame(
  x = c(265, 617, 88, 99, 143, 378),
  above = c(300, 650, 100, 100, 150, 400),
  below = c(250, 600, 50, 50, 100, 350)
) 

    x above below
1 265   300   250
2 617   650   600
3  88   100    50
4  99   100    50
5 143   150   100
6 378   400   350
```

Comment: What if x is a mulriple of 50?  Both the same?

Comment: I was planning to add+1 to the lower if greater than 0 so I don't overlap my bins, but great comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$above = ceiling(df$x/50)*50
df$below = floor(df$x/50)*50


    x above below
1 265   300   250
2 617   650   600
3  88   100    50
4  99   100    50
5 143   150   100
6 378   400   350
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the modulus operator `%%`:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(above = x - (x %% 50) + 50, 
        below = x - (x %% 50))
```

Output:

```
    x above below
1 265   300   250
2 617   650   600
3  88   100    50
4  99   100    50
5 143   150   100
6 378   400   350
```

Comment: This is great! I will give Jon credit based on first response. Thanks though.